# How to check if this sequence is monotonic

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

We are given the sequence, and we need to check whether it is monotonic or not. I tried by showing that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1$, and I came up that we need to show that $3\cdot(\frac{n}{n+1})^n > 1$. If we take the limit of this as $n$ approaches infinitive we get $e^{-1}$. So we get $\frac{3}{e} > 1$ which is correct. However, the textbook says that this sequence is not monotonic. Is the textbook wrong or I have done some mistake in my steps. Here is the sequence given.

$$a_n=\frac{3^n\cdot n!}{n^n}$$

Comment: The sequence **is** monotonic. Your argument is slightly incomplete, as you only show eventual monotonicity, but it’s easy to fix. Exactly what does your textbook say?

Comment: See [Inequality $(1+\frac1k)^k \leq 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200141/inequality-1-frac1kk-leq-3).